# multiple column melt and concat function in python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, melt

[image][Above is the existing table to which I am trying to melt and bring result as under table. The output I am getting is not coming as per need. Please guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qZiz.png)

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)